# Memory allocation on C++ object creation

Tags: c++, object, memory-management, new-operator

The different size of memory allocation is observed during the object creation on class C below,

```
class C {
 int i;
 int j;
};

void f() {
 C *c = new C;
 C *c2 = new C[2];
 C (*c3)[2] = new C[2][2];
}
```

c is allocated with 8 bytes;

c2 is allocated with 8*2+4 bytes;

c3 is allocated with 8*2*2+4 bytes.

Why does c2 and c3 aquire 4 more bytes?

Comment: it's kinda my own homework.:)

Comment: How are you measuring the amount of memory allocated?

Comment: Do not ask homework questions here without showing that you've at least put in a basic attempt to answer the question.  This is dishonest to your classmates and to people like me who are investing their own time to help others learn more about programming and computer science.  If you tried doing something like this in industry or academia, it might cost you your job.

Comment: I think you mean `*c`, `*c2` and `*c3`, respectively i.e. the pointees.

Comment: @Joshua Warner. i've been using `objdump` and trying to understand the disassembled code. :(

Comment: It can become more intuitive with a debugger as usually suggested.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Yes, exactly. c,c2,c3 are pointers that refer to the beginning address of 1st element of their allocated objects.

Comment: @sof, please let me know what compiler does that, I'd like to experiment. I would expect that hack around allocation, like keeping the size of array, would be done internally by memory management code, e.g. allocating 4 extra bytes instead of 2*8... But that fact should not be seen by C++ code - except for watching raw memory in debugger

Comment: @Andrey `g++ -g -c your_prog.cpp`, plus `objdump -d your_prog.o`

Comment: @Andrey Adding `-S` to `objdump` will enable cross-reference to the source code.

Comment: @templatetypedef. i removed the `homework` tag you'd added. This Q has nothing to do with the `homework` you meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember that C++ separates *memory allocation* and *object expression*. The default array-new expression `T * p = new T[N];` both allocates enough memory for `N` objects *and* constructs those objects. At the other end, `delete[] p;` must call the destructor of all those elements, and then free the memory.

While allocating and freeing memory is handled by the platform, and freeable memory is sufficiently well identified to the OS by a single pointer value, constructing and destroying objects is more complicated. The number of actual objects must be stored somewhere, and to that end, the standard permits a C++ implementation to request more memory than `N * sizeof(T)`. It is true that the pointer `p` will always point to the beginning of the array of `N` objects, but `p` does not have to be the same pointer that was returned by the underlying memory allocator. (In fact, `p` is guaranteed to be precisely the value of the underlying allocation result offset by the excess amount of memory.)

The details are entirely left up to the implementation. Some platforms provide additional guarantees, though; for example, the [Itanium ABI](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#array-cookies) (which calls the extra data "array cookie") says that the memory for `new T[N]` will be laid out as follows:

```
+- alignof(T) --+-- sizeof(T) --+-- sizeof(T) --+-- sizeof(T) --+-- ...
| ***** [8B: N] |  1st element  |  2nd element  |  3rd element  |  .....
+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-- ...
A               A
|               |_ result of "new T[N]"
|
|_ value returned "operator new[]()"
```

Comment: Thx for the detailed info. i just figured out the 32 bit platform use these additional 32/8=4 bytes to store the total size of allocated objects by `new []` expression.

Comment: @Kerrek, and what happens if I have an `operator new[] (size_t n)` overload - is there any guarantee that `new C[2]` would give `n` that is exactly 2 * sizeof(C)?

Comment: @Andrey: no no, that is unrelated. Whichever array-new operator ends up getting called will get called with a size argument that includes the extra space requirement.

Comment: Better to be precise the only POD objects have a guaranteed memory layout on all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

From the standard (section `[expr.mew]`):

> A *new-expression* passes the amount of space requested to the allocation function as the ﬁrst argument of type `std::size_t`.  That argument shall be no less than the size of the object being created; it may be greater than the size of the object being created only if the object is an array.

Clearly the standard expects some additional information to be stored with a dynamically allocated array.

Now, use your debugger to see what's stuffed into those extra bytes, and figure out when that extra information might be needed for the compiler to do its job.

(Hint: fix your program so that it doesn't leak memory)

Answer (score 3):

A lot of compilers use the 4 bytes before the pointer returned from new[] to store the number of objects actually being allocated. This is all implementation dependent and it's important to remember that pointer arithmetic that takes you outside the range of memory you allocated results in undefined behavior